# Cómo hago para que un onClick funcione en una etiqueta option

Tags: javascript, html, css

necesito un menu de botones pero sucede que la etiqueta onClick no funciona en ella, quiero saber si hay otra manera de tener un menu de 'botones' ya que no quiero usar más javascript

```
<select>
<option value="volvo" disabled selected value>Ver</option>
<option value="saab">Autos</option>
<option value="saab">Camiones</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Creo que debes usar un `onChange`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que lo que quieres es ejecutar algún código con el onclick(porque no existe una etiqueta llamada onclick), lo que deberías de hacer en este caso no es usar ese evento ya que no debería funcionar con los option del select, sino con el select mismo. cambia el evento onclick por el onchange y asignado en la etiqueta select:

```
<select onchange="funcion()" >
  <option value="volvo" disabled selected value>Ver</option>
  <option value="saab">Autos</option>
  <option value="saab">Camiones</option>
</select>
```